# If I call a class from Main class that extends TimerTask, is this multithreading?

Tags: java, multithreading

I have a simple class that extends TimerTask, which I schedule it in my Main class, would you call this Multi-Threading?

Main class is a Thread and now If I schedule a class that extends TimerTask(Thread) then I assume it's Multi-Threading but I would like to verify.

e.g.

```
class TestTask extends TimerTask {
public void run() {
System.out.println("test");
}
}

public class test {
public static void void main(String[] args) {
Timer timer = new Timer();
    timer.schedule(new TestTask(), 0, 1000);
}
}
```

Comment: Yes, it is. With that being said, this question is rather off-topic for SO.

Comment: Yes, please see documentation at http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html where you will see the tread usage.

Comment: Thank you guys for your prompt response!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `Timer` instance would schedule the `run()` method of your `TestTask` to be executed in a background thread, so yes, your application would run in multiple threads (the main thread + the background thread), so you can definitely call this multi-threading.

Comment: Thank you Eran for clarifying!